# Работы с input - ами через js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Вот познаю js и в результате работы сталкнулся со следующий проблемой.

> Написать функцию, у которой 2 параметра – строка s и целое число n. 
>   Функция возвращает строку, с удаленными n символами с начала и конца
>   строки

```html
<p>введите строку</p><input type="text" id="str">
<p>введите число удаления символов</p><input type="text" id="int">
<p id="paragraph">Результат</p>
<script defer>
  let stroka = document.getElementById("str").value;
  let chislo = parseInt(document.getElementById("int").value);
  let par = document.getElementById("paragraph");

  function funcfortrim(st, ch) {
    par.innerHTML = st.slice(ch, ch);
  }
</script>
<button id="butres" onclick="funcfortrim(stroka, chislo);">button</button>
```

Здесь при нажатии на кнопку должна вызываться функция, которая обрезает строку по параметрам и выбрасывает это в параграф.

Но когда я нажимаю на кнопку в параграф ничего не выбрасывается, там просто вместо "Результат" появляется пустое поле ("Результат" пропадает и всё).

Укажите пожалуйста на проблему. Может быть я не правильно обрезаю строку? Хотя я думаю, что у меня не считывается `stroka из input`, потому что я делал проверку и пытался вывести `stroka.length`, но он выводил на экран **0**.

Вообщем помогите пожалуйста исправить эту проблему, буду очень признателен

Comment: "за место" пишется в месте :)

Comment: Атрибуты `defer && async`  для подключаемых внешних скриптов...  Так что тут в примере они `ни к селу не к городу`.

Comment: можно еще так, однако при превышении длины не такой результат получится :) `paragraph.innerHTML = str.value.substring(+int.value, str.value.length-int.value)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function funcfortrim() {
  let stroka = document.getElementById("str").value;
  let chislo = parseInt(document.getElementById("int").value);
  let par = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  par.innerHTML = stroka.slice(chislo, -chislo);
}
```

```html
<p>введите строку</p><input type="text" id="str">
<p>введите число удаления символов</p>
<input type="text" id="int" />
<p id="paragraph">Результат</p>

<button id="butres" onclick="funcfortrim();">button</button>
```

Comment: для того что бы удалял и с начала строки и с конца поменяйте `stroka.slice(chislo)` на  `stroka.slice(chislo,stroka.length-chislo)`

Comment: твой пример рабочий

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно использовали функцию slice, должно быть так:

```
par.innerHTML = st.slice(ch, st.length - ch);
```

Получается вы возьмете строку по индексу от введенного числа до максимальной длины строки - переданное число

Плюс переписал код, т.к. ваш код все равно работать не будет, т.к. значения stroka и chislo у вас всегда будут "" и NaN

```html
<p>введите строку</p><input type="text" id = "str">
<p>введите число удаления символов</p><input type="text" id = "int">
<p id="paragraph">Результат</p>
<script defer>
function trimString(){
 let stroka = document.getElementById("str").value;
 let chislo = parseInt(document.getElementById("int").value);

 funcfortrim(stroka, chislo);
}

function funcfortrim(st, ch){
 var par = document.getElementById("paragraph");
 par.innerHTML = st.slice(ch, st.length - ch);
}
</script>
<button id="butres" onclick="trimString();">Trim</button>
```

А если прям по ТЗ делать, то сама функция не должна ничего делать с параграфом, а всего лишь должна возвращать значение:

```html
<p>введите строку</p><input type="text" id="str">
<p>введите число удаления символов</p><input type="text" id="int">
<p id="paragraph">Результат</p>
<script defer>
function trimString(){
 let str = document.getElementById("str").value;
 let number = parseInt(document.getElementById("int").value);
 let par = document.getElementById("paragraph");
 
 par.innerHTML = applyTrim(str, number);
}

function applyTrim(s, n){
 return s.slice(n, s.length - n);
}
</script>
<button id="butres" onclick="trimString();">Trim String!</button>
```

Comment: почему в результат ни чего не попадает ?

Comment: @MaximLensky не знаю почему у вас не попадает, у меня попадает

Comment: вот скрин -gif - смотрите : https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6a5wjb625pt1zk/Video_2019-07-19_191724.gif

Comment: @MaximLensky, ржу в голосину) https://imgur.com/lBEnJ65